# Swiper slider add class to active slide when attribute in HTML is set

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider, swiper.js

I want to add class to navbar when active slide has got attribute set for example "navbar-dark". I tried with class but my function doesn't work perfect. It is when I changed slide the class was adding to the second slide not to first slide.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
        direction: 'horizontal',
        loop: false,
        mousewheel: {
            invert: false,
        },
    });
    mySwiper.on('slideChange', function (realIndex) {
        if ($('.swiper-slide.swiper-slide-active').hasClass('dark')) {
            $('#navbar').addClass('darknav')
        } else {
            $('#navbar').removeClass('darknav');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I googled for "swiper jQuery plugin", opened the first suggested page and went to [the API](https://idangero.us/swiper/api/).
And there's the [Events section](https://idangero.us/swiper/api/#events), and there's the `.on init` method. Let's try it

```js
jQuery(function($) {

  function darkNav() {
    //if ( $('.swiper-slide.swiper-slide-active').hasClass('dark') ) { // `this` rather?
    if ( $(this).find('.swiper-slide-active').hasClass('dark') ) {
      $('#navbar').addClass('darknav')
    } else {
      $('#navbar').removeClass('darknav');
    }
  }

  var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    direction: 'horizontal',
    loop: false,
    mousewheel: {
      invert: false,
    },
    on: {
      init: darkNav,          // do also on init
      slideChange: darkNav    // is this needed?
    }
  });

});
```

Also, instead of `$('.swiper-slide.swiper-slide-active').hasClass('dark')` you could rather try with `$(this).find('.swiper-slide-active').hasClass('dark')`

Comment: With You I achieved what I wanted. Thank You very much. I only changed "slideChange" to "slideChangeTransitionStart" and all works perfect.