# Swiper.js with custom animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, swiper.js

I'm currently experimenting with `Swiper.js` and I found a website that use Swiper.js that I want to replicate just the animation. but when I see the Swiper.js `API` I couldn't match their effect with the animation I wanted

[here is the website, if you scroll down a bit you can see a very good looking carousel](https://www.hkland.com/en/our-business)

when I see trough inspect mode, I think that they're using `@keyframes` animation from `CSS`. how can I apply `@keyframes` animation to the `Swiper.js` or achieve the same animation?

here are my code

**HTML and CSS**:

```css
html,
body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: #eee;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.swiper-container {
  width: 70%;
  height: 80%;
}

.swiper-slide {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #fff;
```

```html
<div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image: url(https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/697115145691725846/808955703719886868/download.jpg)"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image: url(https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/697115145691725846/808955703719886868/download.jpg)"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image: url(https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/697115145691725846/808955703719886868/download.jpg)"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image: url(https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/697115145691725846/808955703719886868/download.jpg)"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image: url(https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/697115145691725846/808955703719886868/download.jpg)"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- Add Pagination -->
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
    <!-- Add Arrows -->
    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

```
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination',
    type: 'fraction',
  },
  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
  },
});
```

I'm opened to any suggestion and ways in order to achieve the animation from the example I've provided.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Seeing this link is not without merit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54792366/swiper-slider-add-class-to-active-slide-when-attribute-in-html-is-set